# why same locale but one has error <java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Malformed input or input contains unmappable chacraters?

Tags: linux, locale, nio, file-copying

I have the same source to run STAG and PROD, when copy a file with Japanese name, STAG got error and PROD is no, why?

```
<java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Malformed input or input contains unmappable chacraters: /xxx/yyy/zzz/日本語.txt>
```

Comment: Ha i am facing the opposite! At testEnv all is ok, at prodEnv "randomly"?! fails!

Comment: I am using OpenJDK ver. 1.8.0_232 at Ubuntu 16.04 server